# Get list of hashes and scalars used in current freemarker template

Tags: freemarker

is there a possibility to get a list of all mentioned hashes and scalars used in my current loaded freemarker template.

I have the problem that I have plenty of templates, changing every week, all hashes, scalars are embedded in plenty of html elements. Currently I try to process my database and the template and look for errors, or I look manually into the templates to extend my database.

I would love to have something like

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(new Version("2.3.32"));
cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(TemplateProcessor.class, "/");
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
Template template = cfg.getTemplate("origin-keycloak/themes/base/account/totp.ftl");

List<TemplateKeys> templatesKeys ) template.getKeys()
```

ChatGPT gave me some code:

```
TemplateModel templateModel = template.createProcessingEnvironment(dataModel, writer).getMainNamespace();
```

but this results first in an empty dictionary, and second should be done after processing.

Thanks for any advice,

Greetings from Germany

Henner

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for this. Actually, it's impossible to tell in general what variables a template will try to read (because a template may use `#import/#include`, `myHash[name]`, `someString?eval`, etc.). I guess some utility could be developed that walks the AST, and at least works for trivial templates, but that wasn't yet done.

Comment: Hi ddekany, thanks for your reply: at least I know now that I searched really deep. Maybe I will get a cool idea to get around my problem. Thanks again, Henner